# React-Redux LocalForm cannot fetch values on submit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux-form

I am using `react-redux-form`'s `LocalForm` whose data is being saved in redux store. It's docs can be found [here](https://davidkpiano.github.io/react-redux-form/docs/guides/local.html). I have below code:

```
handleSubmit(value) {
        console.log('Current State is: ' + JSON.stringify(value));
        alert('Current State is: ' + JSON.stringify(value));
    }
changeAction(model, value){
        console.log(model);
            this.props.dispatch({type:'CHANGE_FIELD',payload:{ value: value}});
    }

<LocalForm model="feedback" onSubmit={(values) => this.handleSubmit(values)}>
                                    <Control.text model=".firstname" id="firstname" name="firstname"
                                        placeholder="First Name"
                                        className="form-control"
                                        defaultValue={this.props.fields.feedback.firstname}
                                        changeAction={this.changeAction}
                                        updateOn="change"
                                         />
                                        
                            
                                    <Button type="submit" color="primary">
                                    Send Feedback
                                    </Button>
                        </LocalForm>
```

Below is the reducer for redux:

```
const InitialFeedback={
    feedback: {
        firstname: ''
    }
};

export const formsData=(state=InitialFeedback,action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case 'CHANGE_FIELD':
                return {...state, feedback:{...state.feedback, firstname: action.payload.value} };
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

The data is being saved into the store correctly but the problem is that when I submit the form, it shows me an empty values object, means that it couldn't fetch the field values.

But when I remove those two attributes of Control.text ,`changeAction` and `updateOn`, then it correctly fetches the field values on submit but in this case I cannot store the data in redux store.

Can you people help me to identify if there is any error in my code beacuse console shows none. Also, the docs don't say anything about this!

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I have found what wrong is happening in the code. Actually it isn't because of redux, I think it is a bug in `react-redux-form` because I tried it to use without redux. The probable issue is that you cannot use `changeAction` and `updateOn` with the onSubmit. You have to use onChange!